# django-compressor: Invalid template

Tags: django, django-compressor

I'm using django-compressor for a project, but when I run the `./manage compress` command I got a list of errors like:

```
Invalid template /home/somepath: 'some_template_tags' is not a valid tag library: ImportError raised loading postman.templatetags.some_template_tags: cannot import name SomeLibrary
```

I don't have any extra information. Moreover the application is added to `INSTALLED_APPS` and the template tags runs normally without django-compressor.

**Update:**

This is the `settings.py`file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
     'django.contrib.staticfiles',
     'cms',
     'mptt',
     'menus',
     'south',
     'sekizai',
     'classytags',
     'postman',
     # More apps
     'compressor',
)
# More lines
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
     'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
     'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
     'compressor.finders.CompressorFinder',
)
```

Comment: Can you update your post to include the relevant info in your project settings.py file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was postman. I replaced the function: `get_user_model()` with `User` on the postman/models.py file: